# ggplot2: remove some legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have seen a lot of questions regarding how to remove some elements of the legend (with `guides(... = FALSE)` for instance, or how to remove the titles in the legend (with `theme(legend.title = element_blank())`) but I can't find how to remove the title of only one element in the legend.

MWE :

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 2:6, col = c(1,1,1,2,2), alpha = c(1,1,2,2,3))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(fill=col, alpha=alpha))
```

I would like for instance just to remove the `alpha` title.

EDIT : I know that it is possible to tweak the things manually afterwards by making something like:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(fill=col, alpha=alpha))
p$labels$alpha = NULL
p
```

but I'd like to have it in regular ggplot2 commands, without creating a variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use `labs()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=col, alpha=alpha)) + 
  labs(alpha="")
```

Comment: ok ! didn't know the labs function